# Spring Boot enviar información de Modal a Controlador y guardar valores

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, modal, controller

Necesito saber como enviar desde Javascript información de un Modal al controlador.

1. En primer lugar lanzo el modal que se comunica con el controlador de Proyecto para recoger información y mostrársela al usuario. El controlador la devuelve en texto plano ->

```
    return "<table>\n"
                    + "                                    <tr class=\"row\">\n"
                    + "                                        <th class=\"tableHeader\">Rol</th>\n"
                    + "                                        <th class=\"tableHeader\">Matrícula</th>\n"
                    + "                                        <th class=\"tableHeader\">Usuario</th>\n"
                    + "                                    </tr>\n"
                    + "                                    <tr class=\"row\">\n"
                    + "                                        <th><strong>GdD</strong></th>\n"
                    + "                                        <th><strong>"+matriculaGdD+"</strong></th>\n"
                    + "                                        <th><strong>"+nombreGdD+"</strong></th>\n"
                    + "                                    </tr>\n"
                    + "                                </table>";
```

2. En segundo lugar se pide al usuario que acepte esta información para guardarla o Cancele el Modal. Este es el Modal ->

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                              

    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                      <div class="modal-header">
                                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">¿Desea cargar la información en el proyecto?</h5>
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                        </button>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="modal-body" id="areaValue">
                                                
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="guardarModal">Guardar cambios</button>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
```

3. Si acepta la información, llamo a la función Javascript siguiente, pero no sé cómo enviar información al modal, la recogí con un $.get como se aprecia en el código siguiente, pero imagino que para enviar no es así, y quiero hacer un código limpio ->

```
    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
    
    modal.onclick = function(){
        
        $.get( "/proyectos/recuperaSel", function( data ) {
        
            $('#areaValue').html(data);
            $('#exampleModal').show();//para abrir el modal
            
        }).fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.error(error);
            alert('Error');
        });
    };

    var botonGuardar = document.getElementById("guardarModal");
    
    botonGuardar.onclick = function(){
        
     //AQUÍ QUÉ DEBO PONER??
        
    };
```

Espero haber sido claro, ¿alguien me puede ayudar? Gracias!!

**UPDATE 1:**

Pruebo con ajax pero no funciona ->

```
botonGuardar.onclick = function(){
    
    var tdValues = "t666666";
    alert(tdValues);
    
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/proyectos/guardarSelene',    // Enrutamiento del controlador
        data: {
            classid: tdValues
        },
        success: data => {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
    
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final lo conseguí usando de nuevo el $.get, no sé si es la manera más correcta pero funciona:

```
function function1(text){
    
    //var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
    
    $.get( "/proyectos/recuperaSel/"+text, function(data) {
```